# How to simulate orbits?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, kinematics, rotational-kinematics

I was trying to code a simulator of a solar system, but I cannot find out the orbit trajectory equation. I have simulated my orbits with perfect circles by using the $\cos \alpha$ and $\sin \alpha$, but there is no sign of the trajectory equation.

Also, if someone knows, how to make an orbit from different parameters, like initial velocity, gravitational acceleration, mass of the different bodies... would be very grateful✌.

Comment: Trajectories are in general very complicated and very few special cases have explicit formulas associated to them. The correct way to simulate orbits would be to solve a differential equation (say, Newton's equation). Such simulations are known to be unstable in the long-time regime when more than 3 bodies are present. Nonetheless, you may enjoy Sabastian Lague's youtube channel.

Comment: So, which will be a nice aproach to solve this?

Comment: I only mentioned one method, solve the associated differential equation. There are many examples of orbital mechanics (sometimes called celestial) simulations online. There are also many methods for solving differential equations. The simplest is probably the Euler method.

Comment: It's not too hard to simulate ideal elliptical orbits, although it's a bit more complicated than doing perfect circles. ;) Ideal ellioses are ok to simulate a system of planets orbiting a star (which is much more massive than the planets) where you neglect the gravitational interaction between the planets. If you want to be more realistic, it's a bit more work, and you have to use good numerical integration techniques. It's probably better to ask about this on the Astronomy stack, and you can find useful info there by searching the existing questions.

Comment: @Richard You *can* use Euler integration, but you need to use a very tiny time step, and even  the numerical errors can quickly accumulate. It's generally better in celestial mechanics work to use a [symplectic integrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator) like Leapfrog or Verlet so that your sim conserves energy. Otherwise, the errors can cause orbits to collapse or spiral out of control.

Comment: If you just want accurate orbit sims I strongly recommend that you use an existing library. OTOH, if you want to do this to learn about celestial / orbital mechanics, that's great. But bear in mind that it takes a lot of work to get stable accurate results in multi-body systems. If you'd like to see an example of simple elliptical orbit integration (in Python), with an immobile sun and *no* interaction between planets, take a look at https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/d7878c904df8da838f76dc4a15c6c746

Comment: If you'd like to know how to do elliptical orbits without integration, Wikipedia has good info, spread over several articles. I guess https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit is an ok starting point, and you can ask for help over on Astronomy Stack Exchange.

Comment: @PM2Ring Symplectic integrators are more complicated to implement and my suspicion is that OP hasn't done much numerical work on diff. eq.'s before, so my recommendation was based on simplicity, not efficacy.

Comment: @Richard Fair enough, although Leapfrog isn't really that much more complicated than Euler, and gives much better results, especially with highly eccentric orbits. There are enhanced (higher order) versions of Leapfrog (mentioned on Wikipedia) that are a little more complicated to implement, but IMHO they're no harder to write than (eg) Runge-Kutta 4, which a lot of games use in their physics sims.

Comment: Regarding analytic solutions... There is no simple expression for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, or $r(t)$ and $\theta(t)$. However, there are simple expressions for $x(E)$, $y(E)$, and $t(E)$ in terms of a parameter $E$ called the eccentric anomaly. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation). You can numerically solve $t(E)$ to get $E(t)$ and thus $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.

Comment: maybe this will interest you  http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/phys373/lectures/planetarium/planetarium.html

Comment: If you want to understand what's going on rather than simply plugging numbers into someone else's code I recommend that you do your simulation in Python and VPython/Glowscript.  I found two resources that walk you through the physics and the coding, starting at the very beginning.  [This](https://scholar.dickinson.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1000&context=vpythonphysics) and [this](https://physics.weber.edu/schroeder/scicomp/PythonManual.pdf).  Note that the cover of the latter displays the result of a three-body orbit problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy with an approximate simulation of planets in a hypothetical solar system, you can model the orbit of each planet as an ellipse with the star at one focus. This assumes that the masses of the planets are negligible compared to the mass of the star and ignores gravitational interactions between planets. You will need to specify six parameters for each planet to define the size and orientation of its orbit and its position on that orbit at some arbitrary time $t=0$. You will also need to specify a mass for the star, which then defines the orbital period for each planet.

If you want an approximate simulation of the major planets of the Solar System then the orbital parameters of each planet are available from [NASA/JPL](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?planet_pos) (and probably lots of other sites as well).

If you want to do a more complex and more accurate simulation that might involve, for example, multiple stars, minor planets, and planetary satellites then you need to apply Newton's law of gravity to get a series of linked non-linear differential equations, one for each body. Then you are into the realm of finding an approximate numerical solution to these equations, as described in the comments underneath your question.

[This NASA/JPL FAQ page](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?faq) gives further details and useful references.