# What are the physical attributes of a system containing a group objects bound together by gravity?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I'm looking to program a simple simulation of a multi-body planetary system. However I don't know where to start in terms of the basic components of such simulation. For example I know that these attributes are necessary:

- Mass
- Position
- Velocity (as an extension of position)
- Gravity

However I'm not fully sure on any others.

Comment: There's some useful info in the comments & answer to this recent question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/598306/123208

Comment: If you are modeling the star and the planets as gravitating point particles, then these attributes are all you need.